# Diagonalisable matrices over different fields

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, field-theory, diagonalization

[image]

I believe this fits in with my knowledge of Jordan Normal form, however I am not sure how to approach the question itself? I am especially lost with $F_7$

Answer (score 2):

Calculate its eigenvalues, characteristic and minimal polynomials and etc. iver the different fields:

$$p_A(x)=\det(xI-A)=\begin{vmatrix}x&-1&0\\
0&x&-1\\
-1&0&x\end{vmatrix}=x^3-1=(x-1)(x^2+x+1)$$

Now, hints:

== Over $\;\Bbb C\;$ , the above polynomial has three **different** roots, so...

== Over $\;\Bbb R\;$ , the above polymomial has only one root and then its minimal polymomial *cannot* decompose as a product of **different** linear factors, thus...

== Over $\;\Bbb F_7\;$, the polynomial has another root besides $\;x=1\;$ if $\;\Delta=1-4=-3=4\;$ is a square, which it obviously is, thus...

Comment: An n×n matrix A over the field F is diagonalizable if and only if the sum of the dimensions of its eigenspaces is equal to n. So diagonalizable over C, not over R. I don't understand what you mean by a square?

Comment: "Yes" to your first claim in your comment above. "Of course not", to your second one: the matrix is diagonalizable over the complex but not over the reals, as shown. Not only this: if the matrix is diagonalizable over a field $\;K\;$ then it is diagonalizable over **any** field containing $\;K\;$.  To be a square means there exists $\;x\in\Bbb F_7\;$ s.t. $\;x^2=-3\;$ , and now you can use the well known formula for the roots of a quadratic equation as we're in a field of characteristic different to $\;2\;$ .

Comment: That's what I meant! Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

The matrix obviously satisfies $A^3=I$. Over the complex numbers, being of finite order implies being diagonalisable. Over the real numbers however the only possible eigenvalue is $1$ (real root of $X^3-1$), so if it were diagonalisable it would have to be $I$, which it is not. Over $\Bbb F_7$ there are $3$ distinct roots of $X^3-1$, namely (the classes of) $1,2,4$. So $X^3-1=(X-1)(X-2)(X-4)$, and $A$ is annihilated by this split polynomial with simple roots; therefore it is diagonalisable (in the end the same argument that works for$~\Bbb C$).

If you are unfamiliar with the theorem that says being annihilated by a split polynomial with simple roots implies being diagonalisable, then you can also easily see that $X^3-1$ is the minimal and also characteristic polynomial of $A$, so that its roots *must* be eigenvalues; then having $3$ distinct eigenvalues in dimension$~3$ implies $A$ is diagonalisable